# Как при включении трех элементов автоматически появлялась картинка?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как сделать что бы при включении трех элементов автоматически появлялась картинка.(`<div class="glaz"></div>`)

```html
<div class="ogon1">
  <input type="image" src="images/fakel.gif" value="Total" onclick="TotalLength()" />
  <div class="stretchRight">
    <div class="element">
      <hr class="hr-vertical-gradient">
      <audio id="player" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Второй факел -->

<div class="ogon2">
  <input type="image" src="images/fakel2.gif" value="Total" onclick="TotalLength1()" />
  <div class="stretchLeft">
    <div class="elements">
      <audio id="play" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>
      <hr class="hr-inclined-left">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Третий факел -->
<div class="ogon3">
  <input type="image" src="images/fakel3.gif" value="Total" onclick="TotalLength2()" />
  <div class="elementslar">
    <div class="stretchLeft">
      <audio id="plays" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>
      <hr class="hr-inclined-right">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Глаз -->
<div class="glaz"></div>
```

Comment: А "включение" - это полная загрузка всех трех гифок?

Comment: Нет автомотическое появление четвертой картинки <div class="glaz"></div>

Comment: тут есть теги audio, так что "включение" - это, наверное, нажатие на три элемента audio

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о "включении" всех трех аудио - то у тега  есть событие 'play' (при вставке в дом - 'onplay', соответственно). Можно каждому аудио выдать в качестве обработчика этого события функцию, которая будет проверять, воспроизводится ли каждый из трех треков, и, если такое условие истинно, будет выдавать элементу либо свойство `display: block !important` в css (при условии, что класс 'glaz' включал в `display: none`), либо какой-нибудь специальный класс 'glaz__vis', который бы красиво отображал элемент. Пример простейшего первого варианта:
`if (!document.getElementById('player').paused && !document.getElementById('play').paused && !document.getElementById('plays').paused) document.getElementsByClassName('glaz')[0].style.setProperty('display', 'block !important')`
Вот такую короткую функцию - в onplay каждому из трех треков. Чтобы элемент пропадал при выключении какого-то из трех аудио, можно еще прикрутить else с обратным кодом:
`if (!document.getElementById('player').paused && !document.getElementById('play').paused && !document.getElementById('plays').paused) document.getElementsByClassName('glaz')[0].style.setProperty('display', 'block !important');
else document.getElementsByClassName('glaz')[0].style.removeProperty('display')`

Comment: Речь идет о всех трех линиях 1) <hr class="hr-vertical-gradient">  2)<hr class="hr-inclined-left"> 3)<hr class="hr-inclined-right"> нужно что бы при включении всех трех появлялась картинка <div class="glaz"></div>

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "включением линий"?